# What is the best method to solve congruence equations??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to learn congruence equations for discrete mathematics but this concept is actually giving me a lot of issues. In this instance:

$$15x + 12 \equiv −11 (\text{mod }49)$$

And so I tried it like this:

$$15x \equiv −23 (\text{mod }49)\\
15x \equiv 26 (\text{mod }49)\\
1 = 49(4)+15(-13)$$
(From Euclidean Algorithm)

From here I don't actually know what to do anymore. I know I need the inverse modulo n but I don't know which one it is, and I also don't know what to do with it anyway. Can anyone help me figure out how to solve these equations?

Comment: To solve for $x$, multiply both sides by $-13$

Comment: But that just gives me 15 * (-13)x ≡ 26 * (-13)(mod 49)

Comment: And what’s $15\times(-13)\bmod 49$?

Comment: I want to -95, but thats probably not it is it?

Comment: See the linked dupes for most all common methods for solving linear congruences, e.g.
$\!\bmod 49\!:\ 15x \equiv -23  \iff x \equiv \dfrac{-23}{15} \underset{\times\ 3}\equiv  \dfrac{-20}{-4} \equiv 5\,$ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242), using least magnitude remainders.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $1 = 49(4)+15(-13)$ tells you that $15*(-13)$ is the same as $1$ (modulo $49$).

Therefore the equation you obtained by multiplying by $-13$ tells you that $x ≡ 26 * (-13)$(mod $49$).

Comment: Does that mean that x≡26∗(−13) (mod 49) is the final answer?

Comment: Simply multiply out 26 and -13 mod 49.

Comment: x≡-338 (mod 49) which reduces to x≡5 (mod 49)!

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: oh ok the concept of 15∗(−13) basically equaling 1 was messing me up